# How can I build a blog in a single language that isn't English?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am developing my new blog based on Drupal 8 and I want only Greek version of the blog (don't want content translation). I added Greek language as default and if there is also English then there is a url seperation with /el in the greek content. I don't want /el in the url and I want this blog in single language and non English. 
What are the consequences if I delete the English language?

Comment: You can configure the language prefix in `admin/config/regional/language/detection`. But I wouldn't recommend to remove English if you have installed it as default language and created configuration and content. Better start a new project and install the non-english language as default from the beginning.

Comment: You are right, it is not good practise to delete English. I installed the theme with a bundled profile in order to save time and this profile had already been installed with English as default language. So I am trying to find a solution to save some time. So far i have "content translation" module as disabled

Comment: So why delete English then? As said you can configure the path prefix as you want without doing it.

Comment: So what exactly should I choose in admin/config/regional/language/detection in order to show only Greek content and not English? There is "en" prefix for URL in English. How can i block it from users?

Comment: If you don't want to provide access to "en" then remove this prefix or disable URL based detection altogether. The minimal language detection is to have all methods disabled, except the last one which can't be disabled where you set a language always selected.